# How can I make a hierarchy for Apple Music API responses?

Tags: ios, swift, client, apple-musickit

I'm trying to use classes, structs, and `Decodable`to make a response hierarchy for easy and automatic decoding of Apple Music API response. The Apple Music API response objects are kind of confusing though, and I'm not sure how to make a structure that allows extensibility in the future when I expand the types that subclass other types. Here's what I have so far:

A [ResponseRoot](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/responseroot) object in the Apple Music API looks like this for me:

```swift
class AMResponseRoot : Decodable {
    
    let data: [AMResourceResponse]?
    let next: String?
//    let results: AppleMusicResults?
//    let errors: [AppleMusicError]?
    
    private enum AppleMusicResponseRootCodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"
        case next = "next"
        case results = "results"
        case errors = "errors"
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let rootContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AppleMusicResponseRootCodingKeys.self)
        
        self.data = try rootContainer.decodeIfPresent([AMResourceResponse].self, forKey: .data)
        self.next = try rootContainer.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .next)
//        self.results = try rootContainer.decodeIfPresent(AppleMusicResults.self, forKey: .results)
//        self.errors = try rootContainer.decodeIfPresent([Error].self, forKey: .errors)
    }
    
}
```

I've commented out the `results` and `errors` decoding for now, since I'm not sure how decoding works for those/I don't know what the AppleMusicResponse object will look like.

This ResponseRoot is pretty straightforward, I just have a dynamic class/protocol type for the resource in the `data` object array. Now, defining what an `AMResourceResponse` is has been difficult, because I want to be able to subclass it or make a class adopt it as a protocol, such as when I have different types of response objects I can expect, like an `AMSongResponse` or `AMAlbumResponse` or `AMPlaylistResponse`, etc.

How can I make it so that each `AMResourceResponse` is guaranteed to have the `attributes: Attributes`, `id: String`, and `type: String` fields? Those are the fields I can find that are common between all types of response objects in the `data` field in the `ResponseRoot` object.

`Attributes` should also be defined by the subclass itself, too, because different response objects have different structures for what attributes they return. But all of them will have *some* sort of `Attributes` in the response, so I want to codify that in the response objects well. For example, a [Song.Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/song/attributes) object would have those specific fields, but an Album.Attributes would have different ones.

On top of this, there's a [Resource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/resource) object in the Apple Music API that might be useful for abstracting what a "Resource" means, and maybe it could inform my definition of `AMResourceResponse` somehow, idk.

Here's everything I have so far, if it helps. It's really all over the place though.

```swift
protocol AMResourceResponse {
    
    struct Attributes {
        
    }
    
    var attributes: Attributes { get }
    var id: String { get }
    var type: String { get }

}

class AMSongResponse : AMResourceResponse {
 
    struct Attributes : Decodable {
        
        let albumName: String
        let artistName: String
        let artwork: Artwork
        let name: String
        let playParams: PlayParams
        let trackNumber: Int
        
        private enum AttributesCodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case albumName = "albumName"
            case artistName = "artistName"
            case artwork = "artwork"
            case name = "name"
            case playParams = "playParams"
            case trackNumber = "trackNumber"
        }
        
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let attributesContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AttributesCodingKeys.self)
            
            self.albumName = try attributesContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .albumName)
            self.artistName = try attributesContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .artistName)
            self.artwork = try attributesContainer.decode(Artwork.self, forKey: .artwork)
            self.name = try attributesContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
            self.playParams = try attributesContainer.decode(PlayParams.self, forKey: .playParams)
            self.trackNumber = try attributesContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .trackNumber)
        }
        
    }
    
}

struct PlayParams : Decodable {
    
    let id: String
    let isLibrary: Bool
    let kind: String
    
    private enum PlayParamsCodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case isLibrary = "isLibrary"
        case kind = "kind"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let playParamsContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: PlayParamsCodingKeys.self)
        
        self.id = try playParamsContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        self.isLibrary = try playParamsContainer.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .isLibrary)
        self.kind = try playParamsContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .kind)
    }
    
}
    
struct Artwork : Decodable {
    
    let height: Int
    let width: Int
    let url: String
    
    private enum ArtworkCodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case height = "height"
        case width = "width"
        case url = "url"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let artworkContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ArtworkCodingKeys.self)
        
        self.height = try artworkContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .height)
        self.width = try artworkContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .width)
        self.url = try artworkContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .url)
    }
    
}

struct Album : Decodable {
    
    struct Attributes : Decodable {
        
        let artistName: String
        let artwork: Artwork
        let contentRating: String?
        let name: String
        let playParams: PlayParams?
        let trackCount: Int
        
    }
    
    let attributes: Attributes
    
}

struct Artist : Decodable {
    
    
    
}

struct Relationships : Decodable {
    
    struct LibraryAlbumRelationship : Decodable {
        
        let albums: [Album]
        
    }
    
    struct LibraryArtistRelationship : Decodable {
        
        let artists: [Artist]
        
    }
    
    let albumRelationships: LibraryAlbumRelationship
    let artistRelationships: LibraryArtistRelationship
    
    private enum RelationshipsCodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case data = "data"
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let attributesContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: RelationshipsCodingKeys.self)
        
        self.stuff = try attributesContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .data)
    }
    
}
```

I'm just really scatterbrained from being deep in this and could use some direction as to how to construct this hierarchy. Thanks :)

Comment: You don't need to manually do decoding or specify the coding keys. You can just declare that a type conforms to `Decodable` and if all its properties conform, then the compiler would just synthesize the conformance for you. For example, for `Artwork`, you don't need to implement `init(from decoder: Decoder)` or declare `ArtworkCodingKeys`

Comment: @NewDev, good to know! That helps shorten some of the code, but any ideas on how to structure the entire thing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Apple Music API and their JSON object structures.  so it's not clear to me what problems you're seeing. Maybe simplify your question to a conceptual made-up example that illustrates the issue